# How do I use PathCombine() from WinAPI in Pascal Script/Inno Setup?

Tags: windows, winapi, inno-setup, pascalscript

I'm trying to figure out how to use WinAPI functions from Pascal Script/Inno Setup. I didn't find much code examples how to do it and I'm not a Pascal programmer. Here's what I did so far:

Importing the function

```pascal
function PathCombine (
    pszPathOut : PChar;
    pszPathIn  : PChar;
    pszMore    : PChar
) : PChar;
  external 'PathCombineA@Shlwapi.dll stdcall';
```

and using it like this:

```pascal
function InitializeSetup(): Boolean;
var 
  a, b,c : PChar;
  s : string;
begin
   SetLength(s, 256); { soon it gets working I'll switch to use MAX_PATH instead of }
   a := 'C:';
   b := 'one\two';
   c := PathCombine(s, a, b);
   MsgBox(s, mbInformation, MB_OK);
end;
```

The output is this:

[image]

The expected output is:

> C:\one\two

I'm pretty sure I'm accessing garbage values in memory but I don't know why, how do I fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You didn't specify if you are using Ansi or Unicode version of Inno Setup.

But this should work in either version:

```pascal
function PathCombine(
   pszPathOut : PAnsiChar;
   pszPathIn  : PAnsiChar;
   pszMore    : PAnsiChar
) : PAnsiChar; external 'PathCombineA@Shlwapi.dll stdcall';

function InitializeSetup(): Boolean;
var 
  a, b, c: AnsiString;
begin
   SetLength(c, 256); { soon it gets working I'll switch to use MAX_PATH instead of }
   a := 'C:';
   b := 'one\two';
   PathCombine(c, a, b);
   MsgBox(c, mbInformation, MB_OK);
   Result := True;
end;
```

---

Though I strongly encourage you to use [Unicode version of Inno Setup](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=unicode) and `PathCombineW` instead.

```pascal
function PathCombine(
   pszPathOut : string;
   pszPathIn  : string;
   pszMore    : string
) : Cardinal; external 'PathCombineW@Shlwapi.dll stdcall';

function InitializeSetup(): Boolean;
var 
  a, b, c: string;
begin
   SetLength(c, 256); { soon it gets working I'll switch to use MAX_PATH instead of }
   a := 'C:';
   b := 'one\two';
   PathCombine(c, a, b);
   MsgBox(c, mbInformation, MB_OK);
   Result := True;
end;
```

Note that Inno Setup lacks `PWideChar` type. While it can marshal `string` to `LPTSTR` (`PWideChar`) function arguments, it cannot marshal `LPTSTR` return value. So I've used `Cardinal` for return type. It has the same size as pointer (to char), so a stack will match. And we do not actually need the returned value.

Answer (score -1):

I think (although I haven't worked with *Pascal*/*Delphi* for a while) that the problem is that *C* "strings" (`char *`) are **0** index based, while *Pascal* strings are **1** index based (byte **0** is used to store the length).

So, if you declare your `s` variable as:

```
s: array[0..255] of Char;  //Don't forget to change it to MAX_PATH afterwards
```

it should work. Also use the `PathCombine` function like this:

```
PathCombine(s, a, b);
```

There's no need to assign its result (which is the same as `s`) to another variable (that you aren't going to use anyway).

Comment: Pascal Script can natively marshal the `string` to `PChar`. So the base index is not the core problem. (While of course your alternative code is correct.)

Comment: So is there something incorrect that I said? Does the conversion take place without an explicit cast?

Comment: Yes, the conversion takes place automatically.